# Python requests login Errno 10600

Tags: python, screen-scraping

I'm trying to log in to a website for scraping but get

> Errno 10060, failed to establish a new connection.

```
import requests

session = requests.session()

login_url = "https://nextelloc.nextelinternational.com"
url = "https://nextelloc.nextelinternational.com/default.asp?sec=vehiculos_listado"

datos = {"usu": "xxxx", "password": "xxxx"}

result = session.post(login_url, data = datos)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a good chance this will not work, as I believe the url you are using for `login_url` is not the actual url for their login service. You should inspect their login page, and see where the form actually sends credentials, then try that url.

Sorry I cannot help more, this is a fairly specialized issue related to the website you are using and not a python question per-say.

Comment: So if this is the code <form name="form1" method="POST" action="/home.asp"> then my url is https://nextelloc.nextelinternational.com/home.asp ?